# What are the possible special characters which need to be handled in creating XML?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am writing an XML parser; my application creates XML files. For this I have to handle special characters -- for example I know that `<` should be replaced with `&lt;`, similarly `>` should be replaced with `&gt;`, and so on. What are all the different characters which need to be handled in this way?

Comment: As long as you are using something like the XMLDocument or XmlWriter objects you shouldn't have any problems, all the encoding of special characters is done for you.  If however you are trying to create your XML by concatenating strings then you might want to think again about your approach. Remember, the .Net framework has objects to do all this and more for you.

Answer (score 1):

See this wikipedia article:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

(unless you're doing it for academic purposes, I recommend you use the existing .Net Xml parsing libraries, such as those in the `System.Xml` namespace, or `System.Xml.Linq`.  If you are trying to serialize/deserialize objects, use the built in Xml serialization)

Answer (score 0):

For XML *parsing* you don't need to perform those replacements - you'd need to perform them when *creating* XML. You'd also want to consider replacing `&` with `&amp;` where required - see the XML specification for details.

However, I would *strongly* advise you not to write your own XML API. .NET already contains several of them, including the excellent LINQ to XML. Use that instead of building your own. The chances of you independently creating your own XML API which is of a similar quality are very low, and you'll spend an awful lot of time getting there to start with.

Using a decent XML API, you don't need to worry about character conversions etc - the API will handle them for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [list of XML escape codes listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters).

Use the [System.XML.XMLConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert_members%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class to handle special characters for you:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s;
        s = System.Xml.XmlConvert.EncodeName("valid XML --> !@#$%^&*()");
        Console.WriteLine("Encoded: {0}", s);
        Console.WriteLine("Decoded: {0}",System.Xml.XmlConvert.DecodeName(s));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Will yield this result:

> Encoded:
>   valid_x0020_XML_x0020_--_x003E__x0020__x0021__x0040__x0023__x0024__x002
>   5__x005E__x0026__x002A__x0028__x0029_
>
> Decoded: valid XML --> !@#$%^&*()

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in .NET method `SecurityElement.Escape` for escaping certain (not all) invalid XML characters. Check out this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape%28v=VS.80%29.aspx